# Importance of the study of the diatomic molecule

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I wanted to know the importance and applications of the study of the diatomic molecule in physics

I know that the question may not make much sense to you, but while exposing the solution of relative motion of the diatomic molecule, some students asked me about their applications and could not answer. On the internet, I have not found anything useful, so I turn to you. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Is this question better suited for chemistry.se?

Comment: We wouldn't have much air left if all the diatomic molecules were removed.

Comment: This is too broad to be usefully answered here. If you have specific questions from student you could ask them here, though note that the [Chemistry SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

For example, some lasers based on diatomic molecules, such as KrF, ArF (excimer lasers), are a unique source of ultraviolet radiation. Such lasers are crucial for production of very large integrated circuits; therefore, our civilization would look very different without lasers with diatomic molecule active media.

Answer (score 1):

An example to interest students, which a professor explained to my class long ago last millenuim concerns outer space.

It is not feasible to travel to stars and nebulae (we didn't know about exoplanets back then), but we can observe the light emitted by or passing through them.

So we study the spectroscopy of molecules on Earth and observe the light coming form outer space.  Then we can know the composition of gases from a great distance.

Then explain the many [diatomic molecules discovered in outer space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_interstellar_and_circumstellar_molecules) and even in the sun and other stars.